# Android Holoeverywhere Proguard hell

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-holo-everywhere

I am getting the following error while testing my app in release mode, with proguard obfuscation:

```
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3264)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SystemServiceCreator must be implement SystemService
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at org.holoeverywhere.SystemServiceManager.register(Unknown Source)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     at org.holoeverywhere.app.Application.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
08-09 21:44:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(4465):     ... 16 more
```

My proguard.txt file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
  public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
   public static **[] values();
   public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepattributes Signature 

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-keep class org.springframework.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class org.holoeverywhere.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-libraryjars libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
-libraryjars libs/congregando-message-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-libraryjars libs/gson-2.2.3.jar
-libraryjars libs/spring-android-auth-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-libraryjars libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-libraryjars libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

If i disable the obfuscation, the application runs fine.
Could you tell me what is going on?

Comment: Try adding -keepattributes *Annotation*, see: proguard documentation on annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in SystemServiceManager.java of Holoeverywhere. If you read the code you'll noticed that it is intentionally throwing the error as something is going wrong with annotations

```
public static void register(Class<? extends SystemServiceCreator<?>> clazz) {
    if (!clazz.isAnnotationPresent(SystemService.class)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "SystemServiceCreator must be implement SystemService");
    }
    SystemService systemService = clazz.getAnnotation(SystemService.class);
    final String name = systemService.value();
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SystemService has incorrect name");
    }
    MAP.put(name, clazz);
}
```

A check of the [proguard troubleshooting document](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html) shows that by default it removes annotations unless you add this

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```